# How can I pass multiple compact data to multiple view from a controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller

I have two views files(view1.blade.php and view2.blade.php) and the controller file PageController.php. 
From the controller method I would like to send multiple data to both view files (view1.blade.php and view2.blade.php). For example,

```
class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $a = 1;
        $b = 2;
        return view('view1','view2',compact('a','b'));
    }
}
```

How can I pass multiple compact data to multiple view from a controller in Laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi @Optimus Prime you can not send multiple views from controller. Yes you can use multiple compact like this.

```
return view('controller.view', compact('users','projects','foods'));
```

and for multiple view you can include view2.blade.php file into view1.blade.php file then you can use multiple compact for both views.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use like :

```
class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $a = 1;
        $b = 2;
        $view1 = view('view1', compact('a','b'));
        return view('view2',compact('a','b', 'view1'));
    }
}
```